# How to import github project into Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, import, android-studio-2.1

I tried to import github project into Android Studio by this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0MjorpDWxc&t=47s).

But this gives error, *it is not suitable for this project*.

Here is the [Github Project](https://github.com/kbran420/zebra-paint).

How can I import this project into Android Studio 2.1.2?

Comment: Import as `Eclipse` Project.

Comment: I am using Android Studio How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jus download it from github

In Android Studio -> File -> New -> Import Project and will do the remaining

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Comment: Why youtube video is not working? It seems your solution OK, but why this video is not working? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0MjorpDWxc&t=47s